# Extracting names from a text file using Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a text file which contains lines as shown below:

```
Electronically signed : Wes Scott, M.D.; Jun 26 2010 11:10AM CST

The patient was referred by Dr. Jacob Austin.  

Electronically signed by Robert Clowson, M.D.; Janury 15 2015 11:13AM CST

Electronically signed by Dr. John Douglas, M.D.; Jun 16 2017 11:13AM CST

The patient was referred by
Dr. Jayden Green Olivia.
```

I want to extract all names using Spacy. I am using Spacy's part of speech tagging and entity recognition but not able to get success.
May I please know on how it could done? Any help would be appreciable

I am using some code in this way:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
document_string= """ Electronically signed by stupid: Dr. John Douglas, M.D.; 
    Jun 13 2018 11:13AM CST"""
doc = nlp(document_string)
for sentence in doc.ents:
    print(sentence, sentence.label_)
```

Comment: Show us your code. Show examples where spacy is giving bad prediction

Comment: @PradipPramanick this is my code:

    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('en')

    document_string=  " Electronically signed by stupid: Dr. John Douglas, M.D.; 
    Jun 13 2018 11:13AM CST"

    doc = nlp(document_string)

    for sentence in doc.ents:

         print(sentence, sentence.label_)

Comment: Please put your code in your answer so it has line breaks and everything.

Answer (score 8):

#### The issue with models accuracy

The problem with all models is that they don't have 100% accuracy and even using a bigger model doesn't help to recognize dates. [Here](https://spacy.io/models/en) are the accuracy values (F-score, precision, recall) for NER models--they are all around 86%.

```
document_string = """ 
Electronically signed : Wes Scott, M.D.; Jun 26 2010 11:10AM CST 
 The patient was referred by Dr. Jacob Austin.   
Electronically signed by Robert Clowson, M.D.; Janury 15 2015 11:13AM CST 
Electronically signed by Dr. John Douglas, M.D.; Jun 16 2017 11:13AM CST 
The patient was referred by 
Dr. Jayden Green Olivia.   
"""
```

With small model two date items are labelled as 'PERSON':

```
import spacy                                                                                                                            

nlp = spacy.load('en')                                                                                                                  
sents = nlp(document_string) 
 [ee for ee in sents.ents if ee.label_ == 'PERSON']                                                                                      
# Out:
# [Wes Scott,
#  Jun 26,
#  Jacob Austin,
#  Robert Clowson,
#  John Douglas,
#  Jun 16 2017,
#  Jayden Green Olivia]
```

With a larger model `en_core_web_md` the results are even worse in terms of precision, as there are three misclassified entities.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')                                                                                                                  
sents = nlp(document_string) 
# Out:
#[Wes Scott,
# Jun 26,
# Jacob Austin,
# Robert Clowson,
# Janury,
# John Douglas,
# Jun 16 2017,
# Jayden Green Olivia]
```

I also tried other models (`xx_ent_wiki_sm`, `en_core_web_md`) and they don't bring any improvement as well.

#### What about using rules to improve accuracy?

In the small example not only the document seems to have a clear structure, but the misclassified entities are all dates. So why not combine the initial model with a rule-based component?

The good news is that in Spacy:

> it's possible can combine statistical and rule-based components in a
>   variety of ways. Rule-based components can be used to improve the
>   accuracy of statistical models

(from https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#models-rules)

So, by following the example and using the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library (a parser for human readable dates) I've put together a rule-based component that works very well on this example:

```
from spacy.tokens import Span
import dateparser

def expand_person_entities(doc):
    new_ents = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        # Only check for title if it's a person and not the first token
        if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
            if ent.start != 0:
                # if person preceded by title, include title in entity
                prev_token = doc[ent.start - 1]
                if prev_token.text in ("Dr", "Dr.", "Mr", "Mr.", "Ms", "Ms."):
                    new_ent = Span(doc, ent.start - 1, ent.end, label=ent.label)
                    new_ents.append(new_ent)
                else:
                    # if entity can be parsed as a date, it's not a person
                    if dateparser.parse(ent.text) is None:
                        new_ents.append(ent) 
        else:
            new_ents.append(ent)
    doc.ents = new_ents
    return doc

# Add the component after the named entity recognizer
# nlp.remove_pipe('expand_person_entities')
nlp.add_pipe(expand_person_entities, after='ner')

doc = nlp(document_string)
[(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_=='PERSON']
# Out:
# [(‘Wes Scott', 'PERSON'),
#  ('Dr. Jacob Austin', 'PERSON'),
#  ('Robert Clowson', 'PERSON'),
#  ('Dr. John Douglas', 'PERSON'),
#  ('Dr. Jayden Green Olivia', 'PERSON')]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, helped me! For newer versions of spacy (3.0.5) you need to add `@Language.component("my_pipeline_component")` before the function definition and then add it to the pipe like so: `nlp.add_pipe("my_pipeline_component", after='ner')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import spacy
en = spacy.load('en')

sents = en(open('input.txt').read())
people = [ee for ee in sents.ents if ee.label_ == 'PERSON']
```

Comment: @poim23 I have already tried this but  it is also including Jun 26 as PERSON

Comment: Try using a larger model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it works fine,I'm using `Jupyter`

```
text=open('input.txt').read()

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
sents = nlp(open('input.txt').read()).to_json()

people=[ee for ee in sents['ents'] if ee['label'] == 'PERSON']                                                                                      
print(people)
for pps in people:
    print(text[pps['start']:pps['end']])
```